# Vue version not in any npm list

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuex, git-bash

I have sometime to code with vue and node. I returned to my windows 10 system and using git bash

I have node in my windows system :

```
$ node -v
v12.14.1
```

Then I do

```
$ npm vue -v
6.13.4

$ npm vuex -v
6.13.4
```

So, vue is installed,

But when I do
`npm list` I dont see any vue package
and when I do
`npm list -g`
I get

```
$ npm list -g
C:\Users\spiro\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)
```

So is vue installed in my system or not? How can I confirm and how can I locate the folders?

Answer (score 2):

`npm vue -v` gives the npm version, the `vue` option is ignored, to check if vue cli is installed try:

```
vue --version
```

if it doesn't exist, install it using the following command :

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
# OR
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
My code：npm list vue
C:\Users\99195\Desktop\vue>npm list vue
99195@ C:\Users\99195
`-- (empty)

finally code: npm list vue -g
C:\Users\99195\Desktop\vue>npm list vue -g
D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_global
+-- @vue/cli@5.0.4
| `-- vue@2.6.14
+-- vue-router@4.0.14
| `-- vue@3.2.33
|   `-- @vue/server-renderer@3.2.33
|     `-- vue@3.2.33 deduped
`-- vue@3.2.33
  `-- @vue/server-renderer@3.2.33
    `-- vue@3.2.33 deduped
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).